# Unable to connect to SQL Server on a particular network PC

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-connection, network-connection

I have been developing a a few back end DBs to use with a front end application I'm making. My goal is to deploy these DBs to a network PC (lets call it the target PC) in a SQL Server. I have been using a development PC to build/test my DBs, and now I am trying to test how they perform over my work's internal network, but I am having difficulties. What I have done is:

- Created an instance of SQL server express on the target PC
- Created the DBs from SQL scripts, and populated them with simulated data

When I try to connect to the server on the target PC from my dev. PC, I get the error:

> Cannot connect to {my target PC}
>   A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.
>   The server was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)
>
> The system cannot find the file specified

What I have done to try and resolve the issue is:

- The domain firewalls on both PCs are off
- The server on the target PC can is configured to allow remote connections
- The target PC responds to pinging
- All communication protocols on the target PC (shared memory, TCP/IP, Named Pipes) are enabled
- I am able to connect to my development PC from the target PC, but not the other way around.
- The dev. PC is 64 bit, while the target is 32 bit

As a side note, I understand that a 32 bit PC isn't ideal to host a server, but my project is for an engineering environment, so we don't expect heavy traffic or big data. I had to use SQL in case the project moves into a production environment, where we'd need to scale everything up.

Hopefully someone out there can give me some clarity on this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of SQL Server is being used on each PC? Is the target PC a named instance? What is the authentication mode for the target PC?

Comment: SQL express 2014 on all PCs, target PC is default instance, using windows authentication.

Comment: I believe Named Pipes uses SQL Authentication. Turn mixed authentication on and see if that fixes it.

Comment: No dice.  I tried disabling named pipes as well. No success.

Comment: I've noticed in the _Sql Server Configuration Manager_ on my 64bit dev PC has no items in the _SQL Server Network Configuration (32bit)_ category. Could this be the issue?

Comment: I got it. I had enabled TCP/IP protocols on the 32 bit target PC, but never specified the TCP port. I specified 1433 and now I can see the target server on my dev PC.

Comment: Very good. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to try and help :)